# Configure eclipse to use my own Android SDK (framework.jar)

Tags: android, eclipse, android-source, android-framework

I made a custom framework.jar for my device. This new framework include a new API which I'd like to use in my apps. Unfortunately, besides I included my own framework.jar in java build path, eclipse didn't see my new API and throw compiling time errors.
How can I configure eclipse to use my custom framework.jar instead of the jar within android SDK?

[EDIT]

Based in @Yuri 's answer and some other insights, I created a tool (actually it is a shell script) to create a new platform in android SDK and merge jar files into it. It's available in XDA forums to download as well the instructions to use: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2619775

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To build SDK you should run the following commands:

```
make update-api
make sdk
```

Since the API of Android has been modified the command `make update-api` adds new API. The command `make sdk` creates SDK in `out` folder.

Then to start develop your applications in Eclipse using new SDK you should add this new SDK. There are 2 possibilities to do this. The first one is from the book "Embedded Android". I'll just copy it here:

> Assuming you had already configured Eclipse for Android development
>   using the in‐ structions at http://developer.android.com, you’ll need
>   to carry out two additional steps to use your newly-built SDK. First,
>   you’ll need to tell Eclipse the location of the new SDK. To do so, go
>   to Window→Preferences→Android, enter the path to the new SDK in the
>   ”SDK Location” box, and click OK. Also, for reasons that aren’t
>   entirely clear to the author at the time of this writing, you also
>   need to go to Window→“Android SDK Man‐ ager”, deselect all the items
>   that might be selected except the first two under “Tools” and click on
>   “Install 2 packages...” Once that is done, you’ll be able to create
>   new projects using the new SDK and access any new APIs you expose in
>   it. If you don’t do that second step, you’ll be able to create new
>   Android projects, but none of them will resolve Java libraries
>   properly and will, therefore, never build.

As for the second here it is:

1. Find you new build sdk zip (for Linux it cab be found here
   `out/host/linux-x86/sdk/`)
2. Unzip this pack into a folder
3. Inside this folder you can find the directory which is called
   `platforms/android-2.3.3`
4. Rename folder `android-2.3.3` to `<your_name>`
5. Copy this folder into the following location of the installation of
   your SDK Manager: `android-sdk-linux/platforms`
6. Find inside this folder file `build.prop` and assign to the property
   `ro.build.version.sdk` any negative number:
   `ro.build.version.sdk=-10`
7. Now run SDK Manager and you'll notice that you new sdk is added.
   Simply create new Eclipse project and select this sdk as a target.

Comment: there is not a sdk/ folder within out/host/linux-x86/, there are just bin/, framework/, lib/, obj/ and usr/

Comment: @Plinio.Santos I've added the description how to build sdk.

Comment: Any known way for Android Studio? I tried this and it didn't work (a variation, actually - copied the original and pasted with another folder name, and changed android.jar to a custom one, and it doesn't work).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- create new floder in your project put floder name="libs"
- and include the library here.
- And Run  the app
- I hope it's working

Comment: In this case, I think my custom framework.jar will be included in my apk, is it right? What I want is my app use this new API directly from the device.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good question! Your tip would be useful for Android Studio users as well, I guess.

Just FYI, for IntelliJ users, you can also do this:

1. Project Settings > Modules > click Dependencies tab > click "+" button > select "JARs or Directories"
2. Find the .jar and choose it
3. Move the .jar on top of the list of Dependencies (even before the SDK)
4. Change the scope to 'Provided' (not 'Compile')

By step 4, you can avoid making a huge .dex. (Your apk will not include the framework.jar.)

Comment: Perhaps worth noting, it's the "+" button near the bottom (in the Dependencies tab itself), *not* the "+" button in the very upper-left of the window.  I clicked on the latter by mistake the first time, and it took me on a long wild goose chase.