# How to create an emulator that uses a user-generated Android API

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, android-source, android-framework

I was able to compile my own modified version of the Android SDK by following the answer to this question: [Configure eclipse to use my own Android SDK (framework.jar)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14729793/configure-eclipse-to-use-my-own-android-sdk-framework-jar).

I imported this modified SDK in an Android Eclipse project. After doing so, I'm able to call methods that I added in the modified SDK at compilation time, but at run time the emulator throws a noSuchMethod exception.

I'm under the assumption that I also need to copy the system images generated after the compilation. I tried to copy the files in the folder system-images, and also modifying the build.prop file as in the question above, but had no success.

What am I missing?

Comment: looks to be duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9022750/running-emulator-after-building-android-from-source

Comment: @nandeesh, thanks, but not quite. I'm interested in compiling the Android SDK in a machine, and then in copying the SDK + the emulator's image to another machine. I couldn't figure out how to copy the emulator's image.

Comment: find the system.img generated by building sdk  and then run the command by pointing to the system.img that has been generated