# How to use custom android SDK in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-source

I added a new API to my custom android OS, and followed these steps to create the SDK:

- . build/envsetup.sh
- lunch sdk-eng
- make -j(thread num) update-api
- make -j(thread num) sdk
- The SDK is located under /out/host/linux-x86/sdk/sdk/

Then configured Android Studio to use the new SDK:

- Open Android Studio's Preferences --> Android SDK
- Edit the **Android SDK Location** with the new SDK path.

**Result:** When I'm trying to build the project, the build process stuck with a message:

> AAPT process not ready to receive commands

*In the meanwhile I found a workaround to use the custom android.jar (in answers)*

Answer (score 1):

Workaround for using the new android.jar in Android Studio:

- Replace the /platforms/android-/android.jar with the new android.jar that located at /out/host/linux-x86/sdk/sdk/sdk/android-sdk_eng./platforms/android-6.0.1/android.jar
- Build the project.

**Note:** 
Before replacing the jar file, be sure that you have downloaded the appropriate android SDK from the Android SDK Manager. For example:
If your custom SDK is for android-23, download the android-23 SDK platform.
The compileSdkVersion 23 field in the app's build.gradle file, must be equal to the custom SDK number you created.

Comment: As far as I know this is not a workaround but the correct way for doing this.

Comment: There is a way to add the SDK to eclipse- [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14729793/configure-eclipse-to-use-my-own-android-sdk-framework-jar). There should be a way to do it in Android Studio as well.

Comment: How is hacking a binary download of an official SDK the "correct" way to do this? If I'm Samsung and I want to create a custom SDK for developers targeting Samsung phones, I am supposed to tell everyone to get the Android SDK & replace the android.jar in it with a custom one in order to use my API? Sounds smelly.